# Thunderbird: Quick filter bar customization

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

I am using `Thunderbird` 68.2.2 in Debian Buster.

Normally, the menu bar can be fully customized, by clicking right mouse button.

But, tragically, for some reason, the quick filter has elements that cannot be customized / removed. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The quick filter bar has these icons:

```
Unread  Starred  Contact  Tags  Attachement
```

Only `Attachement` is actually a useful search filter. I am not using any of the other categories, and the icons bother me. I would like to remove those.

But why can't I customize the quick filter bar, as any other component in Thunderbird ? It seems like it has been deliberately disabled.

It almost seems to me like somebody at mozilla is pushing on users their concepts of how email should be organized.

I find especially the categories `Starred`, `Contact` silly, and I don't want to submit to somebody others idea how I should work with email.

Customizability has always been the one distinguishing feature of Thunderbird / Firefox.

I searched for Addons that can remove / customize the quick filter bar, but those that I found "are not compatible" with Thunderbird 68.2.2. That is another story. I think in earlier versions of Thunderbird, I could override the compatibility check. But now it is impossible.

Please help: how can I remove nonsense buttons from the quick filter bar

Comment: I would recommend to give the other quick filters a try. If you e.g. create some Message Filters to tag incoming messages automatically, the Tags filter will become a very handy and powerful tool. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a long-standing, [open bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587476) at Thunderbird's bug-tracker that asks for precisely the same thing you are trying to achieve. So it seems without either modifying Thunderbird or an add-on this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-customize-thunderbird-with-customizemybird/

It lets you dig through a lot of settings.  I am not sure precisely what you want to do; but it seems you are focused on removing clutter and controlling the look and feel, and so I suggest you take a look.

[Personally the thing I like the **most** about Thunderbird is the Unread tab - this is the fastest way for me to get to email zero!]